# Creating multiple folders dynamically if not exist in Box using Python

Tags: python, box-api, box

Can anybody help me , how to create multiple folders with Year format(Folders like 2018,2019 etc if it does not exists) in box inside a folder(named as Archive) using Python.

I have a piece of code like below.However I am unable to create any folder dynamicaly.

it = shared_folder.get_items()
for i in it:
    if (i.name == 'Lithuansa'):

```
#print('{0} {1} is named "{2}"'.format(i.type.capitalize(), i.id, i.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas on how to dynamically create folders depending on whether or not a folder with the same filepath/name exists. I also have some date logic in there that you can adjust.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import os

#Create date logic for folder
last_month = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
Prev_Month_Year = format(last_month, '%B %Y')[0:3] + "_" + format(last_month, '%B %Y')[-4:]

#Set the base folder. All other folders will be subfolders within this one.
K_Folder = 'C:/Reporting/K'

#Set a subfolder
K_Invoices_Folder = f'{K_Folder}/K_Invoices'

#Create a new folder if folder doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(f'{K_Invoices_Folder}/{Prev_Month_Year}'):
    os.makedirs(f'{K_Invoices_Folder}/{Prev_Month_Year}')
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply.However I need the folders have to be created in Box (Apple repository link.similar to sharepoint).So I dont think this code will work over there as Box has a different API.Although I can able to create a folder in box but i am unable to findout a way to how to create multiple folders dynamically in Box.

Comment: Do you have Box Sync or Box Drive? My company uses box as well. I can create folders like this on Box this way directly without using their api / library. If I'm misunderstanding, then apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python SDK.

Starting at your root folder ('0') you can create subsequent subfolders using this API call.

```
subfolder = client.folder('0').create_subfolder('Folder 1')
```

This subfolder will then have an ID which you can then use to create subfolders in that folder.

Additionally, you might want to run a check to see if a folder already exists before this is created. You can do this by listing the files and folders in the folder.

```
items = client.folder(folder_id='22222').get_items()
for item in items:
    print('{0} {1} is named "{2}"'.format(item.type.capitalize(), item.id, item.name))
```

Comment: Hi @ user12030152, Thanks for ur reply.